# Finding input tags and manipulating its attributes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension for fun purpose and I am newbie in Google Chrome-extensions. 
Here is the scenario. I am trying to access the page specific tags e.g. `input` and manipulating with their attributes i.e. assign/change their types.

Could you please give me some helps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a content script that runs at (`run_at`) the end of the document (`document_end`).

See the docs for more info on that:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

In your content script, you can just grab all the inputs and do whatever you like with them:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];
    input.type = "text"; //etc...
}
```